# AssetFilteredError while working on rails with angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

Following this [angular rails](http://asanderson.org/posts/2013/06/03/bootstrapping-angular-rails-part-1.html) tutorial, getting the error of Asset Filtered error

application.html.erb file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Blog</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", controller_name %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
 <body>

 <%= yield %>

 </body>
</html>
```

main.js.coffee [created a subdirectory in app/asset/javascript/controllers/main]

```
 #= require_self
 #= require_tree ./controllers/main
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore

//= require angular
```

Its not loading the angular controller created in app/asset/javascript/controllers/main/mainIndexCtrl.js.coffee

```
@IndexCtrl = (@scope) ->
$scope.title = "My blog"
```

Showing the error as follows
     Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( main.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

But after changing like this its not showing $scope.title data.

Answer (score 0):

Add Following code in config/initializer/asset.rb Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( main.js )